# Sql max trophy count

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, rows

I Create DataBase in SQL about Basketball. Teacher give me the task, I need print out basketball players from my database  with the max trophy count. So, I wrote this little bit of code:

```sql
select surname ,count(player_id) as trophy_count

from dbo.Players p 
left join Trophies t  on player_id=p.id

group by p.surname
```

and SQL gave me this:

[image: BBallPlayers]

but I want, that SQL will print only this:

[image: LonzoBallPrintOut]

I read info about select in selects, but I don't know how it works, I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the expected result if it's a tie? (I.e. two players with trophycount 2.)

Comment: then sql will print both players

Comment: Consider using a CTE. We aren't here to do you're homework for you. If you get stuck, you should really be asking your tutor for help; it's what they're there for.

Comment: @Larnu Sadly, the tutors themselves may poach their "knowledge" from Stack Overflow.  Sad, but a likely possibility.

Comment: I know I do... um ahh.... well... :P j/k.  I'm not a tutor... at a school.... I am at work for other developers :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 surname, COUNT(player_id) AS trophy_count      -- or TOP 1 WITH TIES
FROM dbo.Players p 
LEFT JOIN Trophies t
    ON t.player_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.surname
ORDER BY COUNT(player_id) DESC;
```

If you want to get all ties for the highest count, then use `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES`.

Comment: thanks, its good variant if we will know that we  have 1 player with the biggest trophy count, but what i need do, if i have two or more players with same trophy count?)

Comment: I have given you an option for this, use `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES` to get all players tied for first place.  If you need positions other than the first, then we can use `ROW_NUMBER`; this would require a slightly different query.

Comment: use `with ties`. keyword to go along with top

Comment: @GintarsLazda  I'd recommend reading up on analytical/window functions and play around with the `row_number()` analytic/window function Tim mentioned here. They are powerful and will help you on future assignments/work.  Though I think `dense_rank()` maybe a better option than row_number here.

Comment: @xQbert I also agree that an analytic function approach would be more powerful.  But given the OP's requirements, I might opt for the simpler solution, assuming it completely covers the immediate problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Nod.  gotta learn to crawl before walking usually.  My point is there's more than one way to answer the question and as with anything else knowing what options exists and improve the tools you have give you greater flexibility to solving problems in the future.  Good answer and comments !  it's about future and learning not just what's in front of you; though sometimes what's in front of you is all you have time for.

Comment: Once you throw in more than one group you need to go to windows functions (i.e. adding league or weekly). But at least you did the kid's homework!!!

Comment: @KeithL Or if the requirement changes to getting, for example, the top 3 ranks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    select surname ,count(player_id) as trophy_count
    from dbo.Players p 
    group by p.surname;
)
select * 
from CTE
where trophy_count = (select max(trophy_count) from CTE)
```

While select top with ties works (and is probably more efficient) I would say this code is probably more useful in the real world as it could be used to find the max, min or specific trophy count if needed with a very simple modification of the code.

This is basically getting your group by first, then allowing you to specify what results you want back.  In this instance you can use

```
max(trophy_count) - get the maximum 
min(trophy_count) - get the minimum
# i.e. - where trophy_count = 3 - to get a specific trophy count
avg(trophy_count) - get the average trophy_count
```

There are many others.  Google "SQL Aggregate functions"

Comment: Hardcoding the name to achieve the person with the max trophy count is not the answer.  This implies you know the person with he max trophy count.  Lets say Fox has 3 trophy two weeks later while ball still has 2.  Ball would still be returned in this answer.

Comment: this variant is not good , i used this and teacher say that this is bad variant, i can do better

Comment: @xQbert I misunderstood what he was asking originally

Comment: Like the update.  though since this appears to be a student learning, i'd take the time to explain what the CTE is and why this works and how it handles ties.  SQL only answers may help; but ones with explainations provide more useful information.

Comment: update to represent a proper answer and description.  xQbert Gotta give me a second to work on this stuff :P haha

Answer (score 0):

You will eventually go down the rabbit hole of needing to subsection this (examples are by week or by league). Then you are going to want to use windows functions with a cte or subquery)

For your example:

```
;with cte_base as 
(
-- Set your detail here (this step is only needed if you are looking at aggregates)
select surname,Count(*) Ct
left join Trophies t  on player_id=p.id
group by p.surname

, cte_ranked as
-- Dense_rank is chosen because of ties
-- Add to the partition to break out your detail like by league, surname
(
select *
    , dr = DENSE_RANK() over (partition by surname order by Ct desc)
from cte_base
)

select *
from cte_ranked
where dr = 1 -- Bring back only the #1 of each partition
```

This is by far overkill but helping you lay the foundation to handle much more complicated queries. Tim Biegeleisen's answer is more than adequate to answer you question.